# JavaMail : Folder.hasNewMessages() and .getMessageCount() don't seem to work properly

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, pop3

I have this simple code to perdiodically access a pop3 server and check if there are new messages in the inbox folder

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    try {

        String storeType = "pop3";

        String host = "...";
        int port = ...;
        String user = "...";
        String psw = "...";

        //
        int delay = 1;
        long mins = 200 * 60 * delay;
        firstAccess = true;


        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.pop3.user", user);
        properties.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        properties.put("mail.pop3.port", port);


        RomasAuthenticator r = new RomasAuthenticator(user, psw);

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, r);

        POP3Store emailStore = (POP3Store) session.getStore(storeType);
        emailStore.connect(host, port, user, psw);

        Folder emailFolder = emailStore.getFolder("INBOX");
        emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        while (true) {
            if (checkInbox(emailFolder)) {
                //prepara la notifica per il voice_service
                System.out.println("mes!");
            }
            firstAccess = false;
            Thread.sleep(mins);
        }




    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //return null;
    }
}


private static boolean checkInbox(Folder inbox_folder) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    System.out.println("checking");
    boolean res = false;

    try {

        int email_actual_count = inbox_folder.getMessageCount();

        if (email_actual_count > email_prev_count /*or hasNewMessages()*/) {
            if (!firstAccess) {
                res = true;
            }
        }

        //bisogna aggiornare comunque email_count in caso siano stati cancellati messaggi
        email_prev_count = email_actual_count;

    } 

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return res;

}
```

Both getMessageCount() and hasNewMessages() do not work, because the first always returns the same number of messages, and the second always returns false. What's that I'm doing wrong?
I don't want to use a messagelistener because this code will run on a robot with really low performances..
thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The JavaMail FAQ explains why these features don't work with the POP3 protocol.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#newmsgs2)

Comment: the faq explains why hasNewMessages() always returns false. but what about messagecount()? why doesn't it update?

Comment: It doesn't update when the folder is open because the POP3 protocol provides no way to notify the client that new messages have arrived.  If at all possible, use IMAP instead of POP3.